# Toggle Markers in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a heat map with a toggle button. I am unable to create a toggle button for the overlaying markers. Please see below where I am at with my code. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Please be aware I'm a beginner at coding. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Heatmaps</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=visualization"></script>
    <script>    
// Adding 500 Data Points
var map, pointarray, heatmap;

var taxiData = [
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.123662,-1.643964),
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.634315,2.169605),
  new google.maps.LatLng(42.554742,9.424047),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.858082,2.406691),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.774601,3.084719),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.696036,7.26559),
  new google.maps.LatLng(44.24778,6.899449),
  new google.maps.LatLng(44.37775,4.696981),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.229136,4.864319),
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.629681,-1.859237),
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.094375,6.101822),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.567923,7.754859),
  new google.maps.LatLng(44.849198,-0.541271),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.617936,1.496382),
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.765741,5.532997),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.255505,-1.516551),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.527036,-1.472729),
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.634315,2.169605),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.362713,5.591349),
  new google.maps.LatLng(49.884875,2.312979),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.847309,2.38938),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.839293,2.237662),
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.675392,5.160472),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.881233,2.375416),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.8462,6.509824),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.537399,6.464099),
  new google.maps.LatLng(42.697283,9.450881),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.859741,2.356039),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.286828,-0.398901),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.478419,-0.563166),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.564024,1.457195),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.35243,-0.765284),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.838542,2.251592),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.884131,2.377569),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.538834,5.404427),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.62706,3.861149),
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.094375,6.101822),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.365911,5.786789),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.601986,7.783522),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.311948,-1.562837),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.782467,2.056275),
  new google.maps.LatLng(44.841249,-0.584617),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.985009,6.761768),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.833802,2.231579),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.848392,2.420592),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.489477,-1.483008),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.099943,-1.126837),
  new google.maps.LatLng(44.811935,-0.557277),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.881229,2.332641),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.365911,5.786789),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.649392,5.859076),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.042408,7.412067),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.119265,-1.686494),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.096348,-1.296771),
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.233528,6.43959),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.843394,2.241663),
  new google.maps.LatLng(49.376983,3.314011),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.871061,2.328756),
  new google.maps.LatLng(44.733952,-0.527327),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.224227,-0.873659),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.794639,2.378953),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.341818,2.56375),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.984127,4.719295),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.839293,2.237662),
  new google.maps.LatLng(50.467366,2.994484),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.702575,2.069613),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.88908,2.348273),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.369173,0.710714),
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.148348,6.082363),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.255739,5.85841),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.832222,2.355556),
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.904064,6.352804),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.016902,0.107567),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.963963,1.931649),
  new google.maps.LatLng(50.633557,3.080825),
  new google.maps.LatLng(44.812114,-0.572571),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.721714,7.257167),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.629989,2.316041),
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.840121,0.544357),
  new google.maps.LatLng(50.732621,3.048188),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.075871,-1.837195),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.856803,2.384695),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.604626,1.444205),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.543483,3.699367),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.541147,5.44595),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.582739,7.048461),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.823742,2.138747),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.894501,2.348031),
  new google.maps.LatLng(50.640762,3.028105),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.016902,0.107567),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.812765,2.505835),
  new google.maps.LatLng(49.861383,3.266843),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.93329,6.72161),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.242722,6.014451),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.995656,6.93152),
  new google.maps.LatLng(49.116356,-1.072664),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.698172,7.277086),
  new google.maps.LatLng(50.515557,2.89949),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.568432,5.167227),
  new google.maps.LatLng(41.11574,1.242462),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.870025,2.227772),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.575798,7.105431),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.831638,4.352155),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.853298,2.342974),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.873476,2.331369),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.904009,1.899794),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.324054,5.039088),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.88908,2.348273),
  new google.maps.LatLng(50.515557,2.89949),
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.141102,6.155885),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.888153,3.328836),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.822966,2.341676),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.661683,3.922025),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.594835,3.024943),
  new google.maps.LatLng(50.255477,3.916604),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.837459,2.305306),
  new google.maps.LatLng(49.685167,4.769419),
  new google.maps.LatLng(44.164912,4.621838),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.829325,2.345814),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.855359,2.445231),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.179176,6.445136),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.539447,5.446254),
  new google.maps.LatLng(49.044499,2.108901),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.73408,1.37073),
  new google.maps.LatLng(50.600347,3.052344),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.87922,2.287978),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.273183,5.430614),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.808026,2.192418),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.945108,2.149682),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.861361,5.332175),
  new google.maps.LatLng(41.39402,2.139957),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.571167,-0.930737),
  new google.maps.LatLng(44.335488,2.633824),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.509078,-1.522487),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.432038,2.169639),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.35243,-0.765284),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.808026,2.192418),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.18943,5.716541),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.269575,5.866406),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.381993,-0.341715),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.809224,2.300583),
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.678024,5.521458),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.055106,-0.432195),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.755071,2.308439),
  new google.maps.LatLng(49.400139,2.80382),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.55475,2.003027),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.865074,2.346438),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.95165,6.10581),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.777969,4.827925),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.766823,4.83624),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.118996,6.007346),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.118996,6.007346),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.18943,5.716541),
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.19535,6.298984),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.903045,2.281309),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.899183,-4.097376),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.389805,-0.590545),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.991379,2.051722),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.747795,4.881128),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.50386,5.733533),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.911217,6.163627),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.663739,7.14882),
  new google.maps.LatLng(50.613811,3.04236),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.18943,5.716541),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.415284,6.634407),
  new google.maps.LatLng(44.005968,5.115916),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.852845,1.874855),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.596155,2.294114),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.750018,4.886358),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.512678,5.176868),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.462224,4.934523),
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.077695,6.407744),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.834738,2.321883),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.85764,7.334788),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.886837,2.409455),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.255908,5.90436),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.461481,7.503148),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.785493,7.231573),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.31847,5.042767),
  new google.maps.LatLng(44.777547,-0.647259),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.740128,7.344742),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.118996,6.007346),
  new google.maps.LatLng(49.19316,2.468739),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.843491,2.351834),
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.258296,-0.341284),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.160562,1.544387),
  new google.maps.LatLng(44.857522,0.118771),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.595603,1.448128),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.761436,4.83572),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.34564,5.688499),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.34564,5.688499),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.835035,2.505075),
  new google.maps.LatLng(49.36404,6.151245),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.889481,6.797537),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.837044,2.398231),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.557341,1.376799),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.249231,6.390369),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.743772,4.849373),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.34564,5.688499),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.34564,5.688499),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.34564,5.688499),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.889513,6.797366),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.01578,0.160927),
  new google.maps.LatLng(42.585238,2.442451),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.935889,6.630435),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.840276,2.295195),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.752177,4.840407),
  new google.maps.LatLng(50.418715,1.633277),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.389805,-0.590545),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.179993,5.691712),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.806897,2.422771),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.64152,7.009186),
  new google.maps.LatLng(44.843641,-0.586002),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.598156,1.330154),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.802264,3.263245),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.895973,2.2772),
  new google.maps.LatLng(49.125624,2.209586),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.73204,6.236217),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.512694,-4.068346),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.892075,2.294136),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.572325,5.918308),
  new google.maps.LatLng(42.6058,3.034722),
  new google.maps.LatLng(49.115841,2.419535),
  new google.maps.LatLng(49.242612,4.035363),
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.455822,-0.691506),
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.57319,0.364371),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.590745,1.44569),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.31847,5.042767),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.508278,2.922375),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.708526,2.125599),
  new google.maps.LatLng(44.377632,5.025705),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.848545,2.319217),
  new google.maps.LatLng(48.787471,2.529378),
  new google.maps.LatLng(46.257632,6.108669),
  new google.maps.LatLng(47.05698,6.604106),
  new google.maps.LatLng(42.585238,2.442451),
  new google.maps.LatLng(43.716642,7.26113),
  new google.maps.LatLng(45.18395,5.714772),
];

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.123662,-1.643964),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(taxiData);

  heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: pointArray
  });

  heatmap.setMap(map);

  var locations = [
      ['A.S. Adventure',49.07659,6.10424],
['AU MONTAGNARD',45.838842,1.257624],
['DAVENTURE EN AVENTURE',45.777281,3.067718],
['ESCAPE FROM HOME',45.771264,3.119802],
['ARMURERIE O.D.B',41.939344,8.720587],
['ALTITUDE',48.092798,7.37046],
['AM SPORT SA - INTERSPORT',48.582835,7.741074],
['AU VIEUX CAMPEUR  STRASBOURG',48.582643,7.744637],
['LA GODILLE-SARL / SPORT 2000',48.043285,7.163224],
['LOISIRS SA - INTERSPORT',47.240609,5.986948],
['SA PATRICK SPORTS',48.076367,7.358422],
['SPORT AVENTURES EURL',46.902426,6.357662],
['SPORT ET LOISIRS',49.091438,0.603859],
['WEIGEL SPORTS SARL - INTERSPORT',47.748221,7.337235],
['ALENSPORT - INTERSPORT',48.358839,0.126044],
['MONT BLANC EXPEDITIONS',47.217126,-1.548982],
['ROCHE VENDEE SPORT - INTERSPORT',46.680958,-1.428781],
['AU VIEUX CAMPEUR PARIS',48.849482,2.345298],
['ALTIPLANO',45.088065,5.559912],
['AU VIEUX CAMPEUR ALBERTVILLE',45.677655,6.391796],
['AU VIEUX CAMPEUR LYON',45.756506,4.842133],
['AU VIEUX CAMPEUR SALLANCHES',45.926874,6.639903],
['AU VIEUX CAMPEUR THONON',46.361794,6.459379],
['BERNARD AMOUDRUZ - INTERSPORT',46.202469,6.270037],
['CARIBOU INTERSPORT',45.780777,4.832583],
['COQUOZ SPORT - INTERSPORT',45.921605,6.867754],
['ESPACE MONTAGNE',45.184985,5.771235],
['ESPACE MONTAGNE ANNECY/SPORT 2000',45.936839,6.09028],
['EXPE SPELEMAT',45.450626,4.385943],
['EXPE SPELEMAT',45.062254,5.342146],
['EXPE SPELEMAT',45.767309,4.849234],
['FLAMMIER SPORTS - INTERSPORT',46.067247,6.312707],
['FRASTEYA - SPORT 2000',45.573478,5.955496],
['GOZZI SPORTS',45.362951,5.590641],
['JUGLARET SPORTS SPORT 2000',45.621758,6.774616],
['KILLY SPORT',45.449795,6.979823],
['LE RALLYE - INTERSPORT',45.59453,5.897181],
['LIMONY SPORT SARL - INTERSPORT',45.343875,4.820178],
['MONT BLANC PLAGE SPORTS',45.936305,6.632563],
['MONTAGNES',45.686305,6.568867],
['MONTANIA',45.564878,5.92176],
['MONTAZ SPORTS',45.564608,5.966328],
['MONTEGRE SPORTS',46.071608,6.324332],
['NOGE SPORT - INTERSPORT',45.61695,6.767076],
['PIGUET SPORT- INTERSPORT',46.06054,6.579441],
['REVE DE CIME PARMELAN',45.90411,6.130793],
['S.ABONDANCE - INTERSPORT',45.534469,6.633496],
['SARL RANDO STOCK',45.271111,5.890022],
['SKI ET MONTAGNE / SPORT 2000',45.381142,6.721651],
['SKI SET LA NORMA',45.201273,6.69523],
['SNELL SPORT',45.920732,6.866883],
['SOQUET SPORT - SPORT 2000',45.829237,6.596708],
['SPORT 2000 ANTHY',46.349528,6.437412],
['SPORTECH',45.98172,6.925596],
['SPORTS ALPINS SA - INTERSPORT',45.925299,6.869781],
['TABERT - INTERSPORT',46.194546,6.768534],
['TROC SPORT',45.539641,5.990066],
['ALPIMAT',44.901605,6.632996],
['ALPINA SPORT SARL',43.292455,5.379883],
['ALTICOOP',43.714589,7.262607],
['AU VIEUX CAMPEUR MARSEILLE',43.274218,5.390667],
['BADO SPORT 2000',44.92272,4.908711],
['EXPE SPELEMAT',43.292516,5.382688],
['EXPE SPELEMAT - LA RANDONNEE',43.707764,7.285802],
['GRAVICIME',44.92272,4.908711],
['GUIGAL SPORT - INTERSPORT',45.359865,4.702148],
['LAVENTURE',43.126875,5.820168],
['LA MONTAGNE MARSEILLE',43.287535,5.383852],
['LA RANDONNEE',43.604006,3.873753],
['LE YETI SARL PISCO',43.65905,3.903715],
['MILLON MONTAGNE EURL',44.660839,6.05896],
['NEVE SPORT - SPORT 2000',45.120053,6.113892],
['SPORTS ET MONTAGNE',43.949238,4.810937],
['VERTIKALP',44.555602,4.738101],
['AB SKI / TWINNER',42.503838,2.017524],
['ANETO SPORT / SKI SET',42.999929,0.168227],
['AU VIEUX CAMPEUR TOULOUSE',43.552094,1.50238],
['CASSIGNOL - INTERSPORT',44.031043,1.346924],
['DP SPORT - INTERSPORT',43.319284,-0.346597],
['ESP. CULTUREL SPORT&LOISIRS LECLERC',43.197621,-0.617766],
['EXPE SPELEMAT',43.605298,3.874303],
['ExtrÃªme Latitude',43.497069,-1.493851],
['FREDDY SPORT - INTERSPORT',42.745317,0.563609],
['GALLINERA SPORT',42.503838,2.017524],
['GAM SPORT - INTERSPORT',43.237619,0.070005],
['IGLOO SAS SPORTS - INTERSPORT',43.605604,1.447318],
['INTERSPORT MONTAGNE',42.844216,-0.130779],
['LE REFUGE - PATAGONIA',43.634781,2.243348],
['MILLE SPORTS / Sport 2000',42.674823,2.942569],
['MONTAGNE SPORT LE REFUGE',44.838769,-0.572475],
['ONTARIO SPORT',43.504128,1.395169],
['RIBES SPORT',42.986457,1.144016],
['RUNNING ALTITUDE',43.077753,-0.018655],
['SARL DEGEILH SARRAT BOUTIQUE',42.82124,0.327632],
['SPORT 2000 LONS',43.314287,-0.398382],
['SPORT DISTRIBUTION LABEGE - INTERSPORT',43.616194,1.50238],
['SPORT ET LOISIRS MERIDIEN SPORT',43.242477,0.009326],
['SPORTING CASTAGNE - INTERSPORT',42.873012,-0.002733],
['SPORTS AVENTURE',44.834924,-0.576301],
['STARSKI',42.844216,-0.130779],
['T DE LE RUE - INTERSPORT',42.765975,0.24323],
['TAPIE DIFFUSION EURL - INTERSPORT',43.14494,0.403094],
['TELEMARK PYRENEES',42.720191,1.838971],
['TOB PLEIN AIR - INTERSPORT',46.208668,-1.099443],
['TRIATHLON SPORTS - INTERSPORT',43.645696,0.573071],
['TWINNER LAVELANET',42.923812,1.836026],
['ESPORT SENSACIO',42.543295,1.517122],
['OLYMPIA ESPORTS',42.509984,1.531707],
['DAVENTURE EN AVENTURE',45.776959,3.067596],
['ALTITUDE',48.092798,7.37046],
['AM SPORT SA - INTERSPORT',48.582835,7.741074],
['AU VIEUX CAMPEUR  STRASBOURG',48.582643,7.744637],
['HOFF SPORT - TWINNER',48.454696,7.502258],
['LA GODILLE-SARL / SPORT 2000',48.043285,7.163224],
['LOISIRS SA - INTERSPORT',47.240215,5.987463],
['SA PATRICK SPORTS',48.076367,7.358422],
['SPORT AVENTURES EURL',46.901224,6.362022],
['WEIGEL SPORTS SARL - INTERSPORT',47.741349,7.345685],
['CAP RANDO',46.829082,-1.891302],
['MONT BLANC EXPEDITIONS',47.218504,-1.544658],
['AU VIEUX CAMPEUR PARIS',48.849482,2.345298],
['ALTIPLANO',45.034479,5.530929],
['AU VIEUX CAMPEUR ALBERTVILLE',45.670293,6.357697],
['AU VIEUX CAMPEUR LYON',45.756506,4.842133],
['AU VIEUX CAMPEUR SALLANCHES',45.926874,6.639903],
['BERNARD AMOUDRUZ - INTERSPORT',46.202469,6.270037],
['CARIBOU INTERSPORT',45.780777,4.832583],
['CYCLES JUNGBLUT',46.20055,5.233022],
['ESPACE MONTAGNE ANNECY/SPORT 2000',45.614078,5.993451],
['FRASTEYA - SPORT 2000',45.614078,5.993451],
['GOZZI SPORTS',45.362951,5.590641],
['LA RANDONNEE - CENTRALE PRO',45.180836,5.726793],
['MONT BLANC PLAGE SPORTS',45.936305,6.632563],
['MONTAGNES',45.695403,6.585103],
['MONTANIA',45.570027,5.929571],
['MONTAZ SPORTS',45.564608,5.966328],
['PIGUET SPORT- INTERSPORT',46.06054,6.579441],
['S.ABONDANCE - INTERSPORT',45.537953,6.681683],
['SARL RANDO STOCK',45.271111,5.890022],
['SKI ET MONTAGNE / SPORT 2000',45.381142,6.721651],
['SNELL SPORT',45.920732,6.866883],
['TABERT - INTERSPORT',46.182957,6.743969],
['ALPINA SPORT SARL',43.292455,5.379883],
['ALTICOOP',43.714085,7.262102],
['AU VIEUX CAMPEUR MARSEILLE',43.274218,5.390667],
['FABER - INTERSPORT MONTAGNE',44.387244,6.651621],
['LA RANDONNEE',43.604006,3.873753],
['LE YETI SARL PISCO',43.65905,3.903715],
['AU VIEUX CAMPEUR TOULOUSE',43.55651,1.503754],
['CASSIGNOL - INTERSPORT',44.031043,1.346924],
['GAM SPORT 00802 000',43.237619,0.070005],
['LAFONT SPORTS',43.00622,-0.101355],
['LE REFUGE - PATAGONIA',43.634781,2.243348],
['MER ET MONTAGNE SARL/SPORT 2000',43.237619,0.070005],
['MILLE SPORTS / Sport 2000',42.674823,2.942569],
['MONTAGNE SPORT LE REFUGE',44.838769,-0.572475],
['OLMES SPORTS - TWINNER LAVELANET',42.923655,1.835994],
['ONTARIO SPORT',43.504128,1.395169],
['PAUL ANDRIEUX 00778 000',42.765975,0.24323],
['RUNNING ALTITUDE',43.077753,-0.018655],
['SARL DEGEILH SARRAT BOUTIQUE',42.82124,0.327632],
['SPORT 2000 LONS',43.314287,-0.398382],
['SPORT ET LOISIRS MERIDIEN SPORT',43.242477,0.009326],
['SPORTING CASTAGNE 00481 000',42.873012,-0.002733],
['SPORTS AVENTURE',44.834924,-0.576301],
['STARSKI',42.844216,-0.130779],
['T DE LE RUE 00759 000',42.765975,0.24323],
['TAPIE DIFFUSION EURL - 00394 000',43.14494,0.403094],
['TELEMARK PYRENEES',42.720191,1.838971],
['TRIATHLON SPORTS - INTERSPORT',43.645696,0.573071]

    ];

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var iconBase = '';
    var marker, i;
    var markers = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: iconBase + ''
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }

    function AutoCenter() {
      //  Create a new viewpoint bound
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      //  Go through each...
      $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
      bounds.extend(marker.position);
      });
      //  Fit these bounds to the map
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
    AutoCenter();

}

function toggleHeatmap() {
  heatmap.setMap(heatmap.getMap() ? null : map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <button onclick="toggleHeatmap()">Toggle Heatmap</button>
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your markers array global. Then change your toggleHeatmap function to something like this

```
function toggleHeatmap() {

if(heatmap.getMap() != null) {
    heatmap.setMap(null);
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
} else {
    heatmap.setMap(map)
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Lintu, thanks so much for replying to my question. I am a beginner when it come to javascript. I am not sure how to make the markers array global. Could you possibly provide your solution in JavaScript and html? Thanks again.

Comment: Currently the markers array is initialised in your initialise function "var markers = new Array()". So it will be available in that function only.  What we want is to use the markers array inside 'toggleHeatmap' function. We can do this by moving the 'var markers = new Array()' line from initialise to outside (global scope).

Comment: Change the line var map, pointarray, heatmap; to   var map, pointarray, heatmap, markers = new Array(); // makes markers array global. Remove the var markers = new Array(); inside initialise function.